# asp.net application build failure on Hudson

Tags: asp.net, build, hudson

I am using Hudson for creating build for my asp.net application. Couple of days before builds were creating successfully. Suddenly it start showing build failure. I have not made any change in my code. Can anyone please help me understanding this error.

```
    Task "Exec"
  Command:
  "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.com" "<https:..:443/hudson/job/Gateway%202.0%20Web%20Application/6289/artifact/trunk\Build\Gateway> Build Solution.sln" /rebuild "Debug"
  Cannot find one or more components. Please reinstall the application.
<https://../hudson/job/Gateway%202.0%20Web%20Application/6289/artifact/trunk\Build\Gateway> Solution.msbuild(135,7): error MSB3073: The command ""C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.com" "
<https://../hudson/job/Gateway%202.0%20Web%20Application/6289/artifact/trunk\Build\Gateway> Build Solution.sln" /rebuild "Debug"" exited with code -1.
Done executing task "Exec" -- FAILED.
Done building target "BuildCode" in project "Gateway Solution.msbuild" -- FAILED.
Done Building Project "<https://../hudson/job/Gateway%202.0%20Web%20Application/6289/artifact/trunk\Build\Gateway> Solution.msbuild" (default targets) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

"<https://../hudson/job/Gateway%202.0%20Web%20Application/6289/artifact/trunk\Build\Gateway> Solution.msbuild" (default target) (1) -> (BuildCode target) ->
  <https://../hudson/job/Gateway%202.0%20Web%20Application/6289/artifact/trunk\Build\Gateway> Solution.msbuild(135,7): error MSB3073: The command ""C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.com" "
<https://../hudson/job/Gateway%202.0%20Web%20Application/6289/artifact/trunk\Build\Gateway> Build Solution.sln" /rebuild "Debug"" exited with code -1.

    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)
```

I have got the root cause, It was just because of some visual studio updates. I have revert the updates and things are working fine now.

Comment: I have got the root cause, It was just because of some visual studio updates. I have revert the updates and things are working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the root cause, It was just because of some visual studio updates. I have revert the updates and things are working fine now. Visual studio updates make some registry changes and to reflect those changes we need to restart the server. If your server is in production u cant not get down time to restart the server. If our application is getting build on current visual studio then i dont thing we need to update it.